# USB Tethering not working in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: networking, usb, tethering

Can not get USB tethering to work for the life of me, have been working on this off and on for a few days now. I have a Galaxy S7, I have enabled USB Debugging, enabled USB Tethering, and have tried other USB tethering clients than just my default one in my settings. I run Ubuntu and Windows dual booted on my HP Envy laptop so I made sure to disable all wireless connections (bluetooth included) in Windows and testing in Ubuntu again since that used to or still is a bug.

Running ifconfig with USB Tethering enabled gives this.

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:4a:3e:15:81:2d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 352  bytes 25648 (25.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 352  bytes 25648 (25.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.37.113  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.0.47.255
        inet6 fe80::1617:f7c9:b4e3:cd81  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 60:6d:c7:d7:22:0f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 19893  bytes 2905923 (2.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 51351
        TX packets 3309  bytes 547952 (547.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17
```

Running ifconfig without USB Tethering enabled gives the same result, so it seems that Ubuntu isn't recognizing the device? But when I do have tethering on, it shows up in my network listings as a ethernet connection named "Ethernet Network (SAMSUNG Android)" but says it's disconnected.

What should I do? Any other command outputs or logs that I should post?

Answer (score 1):

The problem not on Ubuntu, I faced same issue on Windows 7

By somehow PC can't recognize Android network with DNS, to resolve this issue, are you using any blocking connection app on your android?

If yes disable it then try use USB tethering, if same problem do the following:

1. Install (Set DNS or DNS Changer) from Google play
2. Set Google DNS

   DNS1: 8.8.8.8

   DNS2: 8.8.4.4

Then press connect, after that try enable USB tethering.

It should work

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in Ubuntu 18.04.
The tether interface didn't even show up.
I tried putting a Wifi dongle in the machine and that didn't show up either.

In my case it turned out that the kernel modules for the actual kernel were not installed, so drivers could not be loaded.

You can check the version of your kernel with

```
uname -r
```

If you don't see a directory with the same name under /lib/modules it means that modules are not installed.

You either need to select another kernel at ubuntu boot stage, or install the appropriate linux-modules-*, and linux-modules-extra-* for the default kernel.